# Oracle apex alternating colors in report table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way in Oracle Apex to have report tables have a different color for every other row? For example, like [this](http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/zebra-tables/). Colors would alternate for readability (the user would better know which line he/she is reading).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always include **CSS** in you oracle apex application. To show you how simple it can be done. [See sample here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=9418:1:106822059178238:::::)

[image]

**Easy Way**

1. Edit your page
2. In CSS -> Inline section enter code:

   ```
   table.apexir_WORKSHEET_DATA tr.odd td  {
      background-color: #def !important; 
      border-bottom: 1px solid #cef !important; 
   }
   ```

Now you can take it to new level adding custom css to you application. [See here how to.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35125/ui_custom_css.htm#HTMDB06009)